# pandas create a column to compare a value with one week ago

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe and the index column is time with hourly precision. I want to create a new column that compares the value of the column "Sales number" at each hour with the same exact time one week ago.
I know that it can be written in using *shift* function:

```
df['compare'] = df['Sales'] - df['Sales'].shift(7*24)
```

But I wonder how can I take advantage of the date_time format of the index. I mean, is there any alternatives to using `shift(7*24)` when the index is in `date_time` format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something with

```
df['Sales'].shift(7,freq='D')
```